# Cancel Server Manager feature installation

Tags: windows, telnet, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I tried to install Telnet Client feature using Server Manager in a Windows Server 2016 and now is completely stuck at running stage. Now I just want to cancel this but there is no option anywhere. Reboot is not an option. I googled for a solution and was not able to find anything useful. I have tried to run the installation on Powershell and it gets stuck at 20%, also removing it but is not listed obviously. I tried also to kill the "msiserver" task and restart Windows Installer. I found also a possible solution to rename the Server Manager cache registry. No results.

Answer (score 3):

Well, found the solution. The service that manage Server Manager features installation is "Windows Modules Installer". It is not possible to manually restart it. To do so, go and kill task named "TrustedInstaller" (close Server Manager before). Service will stop. Start it. Open Server Manager and feature installation should be gone.